# Why < Frame > in < TabContentItem > doesn't work in < Page >? Issue using Frame while implementing Tab

Tags: nativescript

The following code doesn't work

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
 <GridLayout>

 </GridLayout>
 <Tabs>
  <TabStrip>
   <TabStripItem>
     <Label text="Home"></Label>
     <Image src="res://home"></Image>
  </TabStripItem>

  <TabStripItem>
    <Label text="Settings"></Label>
    <Image src="res://settings"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>

   </TabStrip>


   <TabContentItem>
     <Frame defaultPage="frame-one/frame-one-page" />
   </TabContentItem>

   <TabContentItem>
   <Frame defaultPage="frame-two/frame-two-page" />
  </TabContentItem>
 </Tabs>
</Page>
```

Whereas the following code works perfectly:

```
 <GridLayout>

 </GridLayout>
 <Tabs>
  <TabStrip>
   <TabStripItem>
     <Label text="Home"></Label>
     <Image src="res://home"></Image>
  </TabStripItem>

  <TabStripItem>
    <Label text="Settings"></Label>
    <Image src="res://settings"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>

   </TabStrip>


   <TabContentItem>
     <Frame defaultPage="frame-one/frame-one-page" />
   </TabContentItem>

   <TabContentItem>
   <Frame defaultPage="frame-two/frame-two-page" />
  </TabContentItem>
 </Tabs>
```

If I remove < page > from my app I will have problem navigating to this page. So, How can I use < Frame > so that I will get tabs and will have no problems navigating to this page?

Comment: That depends on what is the container element of Page, It should be a Frame.

Comment: Do you mean container elements of frame-one-page?

Comment: Yes, please post related code. A playground sample would be better.

Comment: Here is the URL to my code in play.nativescript.org [https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=nTii28](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=nTii28)

Comment: Just your path to page was not correct, I don't see any other major issues here - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=nTii28&v=4

Comment: Thanks Manoj. It worked